# Running symfony 2 on Virtual Box Ubuntu

Tags: symfony, virtualbox

How the localhost part applies when using a virtual machine to run symfony 2? For example (source: https://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html#running-the-symfony-application): When I see the following on my command prompt: [image: CMD]

and enter the browser on my host client, entered http://localhost:8000, the page is not found. When I enter my puphpet virtual host in my browser however, the var/www/index.html is loaded correctly.

Symfony 2 is installed on the virtual machine.

How can I make symfony('s default template) visible on my browser?
Did I forget something, am I missing something or should I read up something?

Edit: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] Returned 192.168.56.1 instead of 192.168.56.101.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to open http://localhost:8000 on your host then browser calls to your localhost to open this page. Check the IP address of your VM (ifconfig) then on host machine you could call: VM_IP_ADDRESS:8000.

Comment: Yes, so now typue in your browser: 192.168.56.101:8000 and you should get your symfony page.

Comment: I did an echo on the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable in app_dev.php and seems like it returned 192.168.56.1 instead of 192.168.56.101 therefor not finding the page I suppose. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using PHP's built-in server! PuPHPet has support for both Nginx and Apache. Considering that I see `/var/www/awesome` tells me that you have either one of those installed.

You should use vhosts to access your app, and add the entry into your system's hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Linux/OSX).

Comment: You mean adding the private network ip address of the virtual machine to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
https://i.gyazo.com/6a6c02ec607af2ef6c18ee5ab1f6e170.png